# What is optimal number of Stages in Spark App?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there some rule of thumb or best practice regarding number of stages in Spark job?
When do you consider breaking job in smaller pieces?

I found smaller jobs easier to analyze and optimize, but on the other hand loading/extracting data between each job comes with a cost.

Comment: Perhaps this would help you 
http://balajireddyblog.blogspot.com/2017/01/spark-execution.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard rule about optimal number of Stages for a Spark App.

- It depends on what your functionality is that dictates the number of Stages.
- Certain aspects result in Stages due to the Spark Architecture - which makes sense.
- But Catalyst & Tungsten optimize and fuse code but cannot obviate 'shuffle boundaries" which means a new Stage.That is also not their task. The DAG Scheduler (underwater for Dataframes) does that.
- You can .cache things to reduce re-computation for subsequent Actions in a Spark App, but that has a certain cost as well.
- You can use things that reduce "shuffling", e.g. reduceByKey for legacy RDDs.
- For Dataframes, DataSets Spark will generate more optimum Execution Plans (in general) and indeed some extra Stages (for computing pivot vales when using `pivot`.)
- You sort of answer partially your own question with the aspect of writing, loading, but `bucketBy` can help wth such an approach. However, I am not sure how why the complexity is more with a larger Spark App - unless you mean using intermediate tables with less JOINs, UNIONs in smaller pieces. But the number of Stages then is only a consequence, and not so much a deciding factor for Stages.

Comment: `> using intermediate tables with less JOINs, UNIONs in smaller pieces`

This specifically. More joins, unions etc. makes plan less readable and harder to work with for me. I was wondering if there is some general recommendation about this.

Comment: If u have a really large complex single query then things can go wrong as in bad performance like in ORACLE and as in Spark. We have had use cases where as you state we split up and it ran fine. So u r correct but that is less than a number of Stages approach --> more a consequence.

Comment: single i meant to say